# how to disable usb based on vendor id in linux environment?

Tags: usb, syslinux

I want to disable usb based on vendor id in linux environment. i want to allow only specific usb's only based on vendor id.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using `udev` rules, but is probably not easy and will require some experimentation. It is possible to accidentally do bad things like blocking your mouse and keyboard from working requiring restore with a live USB stick. I haven't tested these commands, caveat emptor.

Create a new file with a low priority number, eg `/lib/udev/rules.d/20-block-usb.rules` with contents:

```
BUS=="usb", PROGRAM="/bin/filter_usb.sh %s{idVendor} %s{idProduct}", RESULT!="allow", OPTIONS+="ignore_device"
```

When a USB device is inserted, `/bin/filter_usb.sh` should be called with the `vendor` and `product` IDs of the device as arguments, and unless it echoes `allow` then the device should be ignored, eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
vendor=$1
product=$2

if [ "$vendor" = "0123" ]; then
    if [ "$product" = "4567" ]; then
        echo allow
    fi
fi
```

You will probably want to look into `udevtest` for experimenting with rules, and as noted, you need to make sure your mouse, keyboard etc are whitelisted. You may want to restrict the blocking rule only to USB block devices by adding `SUBSYSTEM=="block",` before `PROGRAM` in the original rule.

Comment: i have one doubt where we have to add a rule. is it in /etc/udev/rules.d/rule files or /lib/udev/rules.d/rule files.

Comment: the rule is not working